# Guard against divide-by-0 in a LINQ groupby select statement

Tags: linq

I have the following LINQ statement:

```
var result = CommisionDataContext.COMMISSIONS
    .Where(c.PRODUCT == 'Computer')
    .GroupBy(g => new 
        {
            CostCenter = g.COST_CENTER,
            Product = g.PRODUCT,
        }
    .Select(group => new
        {
            Revenue = group.Sum(p => p.REVENUE),
            Volume = group.Sum(p => p.VOLUME),
            Avg = group.Sum(p => p.REVENUE) / group.Sum(p => p.VOLUME),
        });
```

How can I guard against the Divide by zero exception which could happen, and if it does I just want Avg to be equal to 0.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid summing more than necessary, you should be able to do something like this (note that your code does not compile, however):

```
   ...
   .Select(group => new
   {
      Revenue = group.Sum(p => p.REVENUE),
      Volume = group.Sum(p => p.VOLUME)          
   })
   .Select(item => new
   {
      item.Revenue,
      item.Volume,
      Avg = item.Volume == 0 ? 0 : item.Revenue / item.Volume
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful because C# **Double** can handle **Infinity** values, in fact if you try

```
        var x = 5.0 / 0.0
```

you will find that x = Infinity (without Exception) and this is really different from 0! So, if you want your AVG = 0 be sure it's correct from a mathematical and representational point of view (for example I work with marketing formulas and charts and it's important to know if my AVG is a true 0 or an approximation to avoid wrong charts representation and misconception).

Anyway, this code avoids a *Divide by zero Exception* (you need to set AVG as Double) if you find useful the exact value of AVG operation taking care of the **Infinity** return value if the volumes sum is 0.

`Avg = Convert.ToDouble(group.Sum(p => p.REVENUE)) / group.Sum(p => p.VOLUME))`

Otherwise you can use the "check before" approach with a single evaluation.

```
var x = Convert.ToDouble(group.Sum(p => p.REVENUE)) / group.Sum(p => p.VOLUME));
Avg = Double.IsInfinity(x)? 0 : x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
Avg = group.Sum(p => p.REVENUE) / group.Sum(p => p.VOLUME),
```

with

```
Avg = group.Sum(p => p.VOLUME) == 0 
    ? 0 
    : group.Sum(p => p.REVENUE) / group.Sum(p => p.VOLUME),
```

Comment: It may be a good idea to store the value of group.Sum(p => p.VOLUME) before evaluating that, to prevent the sum from being calculated twice.

Comment: @Joshua - Good idea. You could do that with a `let` statement if using query syntax but I don't think it can be done with method syntax.